# What's causing the whitespace in internet explorer 9

Tags: jquery, css, layout, internet-explorer-9, whitespace

http://mimictrading.com/index.php

Displays the intended way in FF.  IE9 has some weird space on the top, and above the recent topics list.  Not sure if they are connected.  I've tracked down the space to div id="header"

From there inspect element doesn't reveal much to me.

I recently added jquery, I've done lots of modding.  I don't know if this is the result of a widget, script, or css, though it's typically css.  I want to say that I would have noticed this if it was always going on, and it must be something I did, but some changes can't be easily reverted as I don't remember how they were.

Part of getting jquery to work involved changing the doctype to html 5 compatible, removing a line about IE compatibility that I can't remember what it said, but for some reason it didn't allow getElementsByTagName or somesuch.  Yes it's a tangled web I've woven, but maybe someone can identify what's causing the odd difference.

Also curious if it's happening in ie10, if you have it and can see, let me know.

edit: ok adding this removes all but a sliver:

But I don't want that lol.  Does that help anyone figure out how I can fix it for real?  With the above my portfolio tickers for jquery won't work.

Comment: You CSS for #main  sets line-height to 140% try to remove that and see if it makes difference

Comment: tried it, no change.  That was an original unmodified element for this forum style.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is actually coming from the `<a name="start_here"></a>`.

You have 3 empty elements there:

```
<a id="top" name="top" accesskey="t"></a>
<div id="page-header"></div>
<a name="start_here"></a>
```

The first one `<a id="top>` has `position: absolute` (it has a layout).

The second is a `<div>` so is `display: block` by default (it has a layout).

The last one, has no styling, and I think this is causing a '[hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)' bug for you.

It can be fixed by adding `float: left` or `position: absolute` or `display: block`.

Comment: Removed all 3 elements completely.  No change on ie9.  Like the other answer, all of those came with this style (I'm just pretty sure I screwed something up with tinkering and don't know when or what).

Answer (score 0):

It was the hasLayout IE bug.  Changing a couple elements to line-height 0px fixed it, but complicates styling it properly.

Thanks guys.

for more info http://www.table2css.com/articles/white-space-lines-internet-explorer-caused-elements-have-layout

Comment: IE9 shouldn't have the `hasLayout` bug. If you're seeing it, then it probably means that IE is rendering your site in quirks mode or compatibility mode. You probably want to deal with that and get it into standards mode, because the other modes can cause other things to break.

Comment: I will look into that, did no one else see it before I changed line-height, or did no one have ie9?  I don't suppose anyone can tell me how to vertically center the topic titles under recent updates, been trying to fix that forever and now it's really starting to bother me.